# why json array retrieve just first record

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

that problem is about parsing json from mysql. I want to make a login page in my android application. 
**this is my problem:** while the app is in debugging state (actually while running!) the value of response(String json) contain all element and then it refer them to my ParseJSONuser. in this activity, the value of jsonObject contain all element in json too, but in my jsonArray, I see the first record of json and, of course jsonArray.length() = 1, **why jsonArray retrieve just first element (or one record of json).**

this is ParseJSON class:

```
public class ParseJSONUser {

private static String name_get, pass_get, email_get, imageid_get, credit_get, state_get;

public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "user";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String KEY_PASS = "pass";
public static final String KEY_IMAGEID = "imageid";
public static final String KEY_CREDIT = "credit";
public static final String KEY_STATE = "state";

public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> repository;

private JSONArray jsonArray = null;

private String json;

public ParseJSONUser(String json){
    this.json = json;
}

protected void parseJSONuser(){

    repository = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {

        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

        for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length() ; i++){
            JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            name_get = jo.getString(KEY_NAME);
            email_get = jo.getString(KEY_EMAIL);
            pass_get = jo.getString(KEY_PASS);
            imageid_get = jo.getString(KEY_IMAGEID);
            credit_get = jo.getString(KEY_CREDIT);
            state_get = jo.getString(KEY_STATE);

            ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
            al.add(0,name_get);
            al.add(1,email_get);
            al.add(2, pass_get);
            al.add(3, imageid_get);
            al.add(4, credit_get);
            al.add(5, state_get);

            repository.add(al);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and, I used this method for get data from host in my activity (its clear!)

```
    private void sendRequest() {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(URL_GET,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    checkJSONuser(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(GateActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

and, I have php file in my host for getting all of the table (It work good) 
this is my php code: https://gist.github.com/sadeghmohebbi/ef6e1e7b5a529596396a7d58f462ef7e

sorry about my english. please help...thanks

Comment: Its not work again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are always getting the first position in your loop.
You should use the `i` parameter:

```
...
for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length() ; i++){
    JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
...
```

Comment: not difference...in my jsonArray has just one record. thanks but it is not work for me...I check it in debug

Comment: Please post your Json, probably you are using the wrong tags

Comment: here is my php file and result(json): https://gist.github.com/sadeghmohebbi/ef6e1e7b5a529596396a7d58f462ef7e

Comment: As I see in the example the root is not an Array. You should have `users[{"user"}..{"user"}]`

Comment: what shall I do? I didnt learn php well. please help me about this coding

Comment: my php code is wrong and I try to fix it but I cant. can you make a sample php file (server side) that retrieve all data from mysql? here is the php code: https://gist.github.com/sadeghmohebbi/ef6e1e7b5a529596396a7d58f462ef7e

Comment: see this page: https://gist.github.com/sadeghmohebbi/ef6e1e7b5a529596396a7d58f462ef7e